# FindFirstFile Always Returning Invalid Handle

Tags: c++, windows

My aim is to list the textfiles in a specific directory and let the user load one of the files.

I'm using Windows, Unicode is predefined in my compiler.

Question: FileHandle has always INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. What's the cause of this and how can I correct it?

My last code looks like this:

```
ListAllTxtFiles(L"C:\\Users\\Tnc\Desktop\\Yazılım Çalışmaları\\Projects\\Oyun Projem\\data\\SaveFiles\\");

void ListAllTxtFiles(const wchar_t *Directory)
{
    TCHAR Buffer[2048];
    wsprintf(Buffer, L"s%*.txt", Directory);//there are security considerations about this function

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindData;
    HANDLE FileHandle = FindFirstFileW(Buffer, &FindData);

    if (FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not find any files..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        do 
        {
            printf("Found %s\\%s\n", Directory, FindData.cFileName);

        } while (FindNextFile(FileHandle, &FindData));
        CloseHandle(FileHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the outcome from [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: `GetLastError` will answer this question for you. Most likely the path is incorrect.

Comment: John already answered your question. Your format string in `wsprintf()` is malformed, which causes `Buffer` to receive bad data, so `FindFirstFileW()` fails.  On a side note, you are using `FindFirstFileW()` directly, so `Buffer` should be declared as `WCHAR` instead of `TCHAR`, and `wsprintf()` should be `wsprintfW()`. And since `cFileName` is a `WCHAR[]` in `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, to print it as a Unicode string, you need to either use `wprintf()` instead of `printf()`, or at least use `%ls` instead of `%s` in `printf()`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you. Your comment helped me to understand the process better.

Answer (score 2):

```
wsprintf(Buffer, L"s%*.txt", Directory);
```

should be

```
wsprintf(Buffer, L"%s*.txt", Directory);
```

You just got your wsprintf format string wrong.

Comment: If you knew how many hours I've spent to solve this you would cry because of grief. Thanks :D

Comment: But I can only get the first letter of the file. For example I get dor a .txt file named "what" just the letter w. Why does this occur?

Comment: 'Cause you probably should print using `wprintf` or some such?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer so that you don't waste people's time reading about a problem which is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
 #undef UNICODE /* We want to use ANSI */
 #include <Windows.h>
```